# How to write js code with minimal number of jumps required to reach target with less time complexity

Tags: javascript, time-complexity

I wrote like below. But how to make it more efficient. Need suggestions!!

```
For example, given:
      X = 10
      Y = 85
      D = 30
```

Y is the target, D is the jumpcount , X is the current position .

```
function solution(X, Y, D) {

   for(var i =1; X<=Y; i++){
       X = X+D;
       if( X >= Y ){
           return i;
       }
   }
}
```

The above code works fine, but how to write efficiently?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about `Math.ceil((Y-X)/D)`?

Comment: I guess he counts incomplete jump still as "needed" jump, so I used `ceil`, but depends on what he really needs.

Comment: What do you expect the return value to be when `Y > X` and `D <= 0`? Do you want it to return `Infinity`, or not return at all (like your current algorithm)?

Comment: I suggest you name your functions and variables better, for instance `function countJumps(startIndex, targetIndex, jumpSteps)`. It helps reading your code and finding a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to simulate jumping, You can just use maths:

```
(X >= Y) ? 1 : Math.ceil((Y-X)/D)
```

EDIT: Updated for `x >= y` according to Patrick Robert's suggestion.

Comment: Another issue is when `D < 0`, this returns a finite negative value. For a one-liner it should probably return `Infinity` by dividing by `Math.max(D, 0)` instead of `D`, but it's possible that according to the example algorithm, it should not return at all. *Shrug*

Comment: if X == Y  1 step? why not 0?

Comment: @Emeeus: Because the original function, that radiance88 used in his question, does so. 0 would make more sense to me, too.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question (*minimal number of jumps required*),  as I understand, when x==y should be 0 steps, then:

```
Math.ceil(Math.abs((Y-X)/D))
```

works when Y<0 and/or X<0